# Transfering a PDF File via Action Extension from Safari to App

Tags: ios, pdf, safari, ios-app-extension

I want to use an action extension to transfer a PDF file from Safari to my host application.

If the user opens a PDF file in Safari, the extension should copy the local file to my app.
Somehow the NSItemProvider only has Items conforming to the type 'public.url'.
This is the web-URL to the file, but not the local filepath that I want.

Can someone point me in the right direction here?

Answer (score 1):

I came across the same scenario yesterday. What I did was

```
let url: URL = (result as? URL)!
        let path: String = url.path

        if path.hasSuffix(".pdf") {
           //download the data from url and write to a pdf file
        }
```